# Tablespace y archivos de datos en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Un tablespace es un archivo de datos que almacena varias tablas, como un archivo zip? ¿Cuál es la relación entre tablespace y el archivo de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Oracle, un **Tablespace** es un espacio lógico, es el almacenamiento básico de todos los datos, efectivamente la analogía de un contenedor de tablas como un archivo zip se acerca bastante, salvo que el **tablespace** no es un contenedor físico sino lógico. Una base de datos se compone de uno o mas "**tablespaces**". Cada uno de estos, se administra mediante uno o mas **Datafiles** que estos sí son archivos físicos a nivel del sistema operativo. Una forma de entender esto es, por ejemplo, cuando administramos un tablespace enorme y que queremos distribuir en distintos discos, tendremos tantos **datafiles** como discos pero un único tablespace. Esta forma de administración nos permite eventualmente ir aumentando el tamaño de un **tablespace** añadiendo **datafiles** de acuerdo a nuestras necesidades.

La documentación oficial [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm#i2009).

Comment: Muchas gracias!